# how to treat byte arrays like lists?

Tags: groovy

I want to drop the last element of a byte array

but neither of these methods seems to be supported

```
def test = 'test.com'
print test.bytes.removeLast()
print '\n'
print test.bytes.dropRight(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are arrays and they don't have much features at all in Groovy.  You can transform them into a list with `.toList()`

```
groovy:000> test.bytes.toList().removeLast()
===> 109
```